# php mysql edit table form revert the table's fields to it's original values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a form for editing a table in the database, when I edit a table using the forms it do nothing and give no errors.
But when I edit it from phpMyAdmin it works, but if I edit it back using the php form it reverts the fields values to it's original values that I gave it in the add form.
I'm using pdo class to connect to the mysql database.

Here is the php code to edit the table, it's kinda miss I know :/, note that I store the form values in arrays because I have a for loop in creating the form so it give fields for each employee and of course I change the name of the fields using a prefix:

```
<?php
if((isset($_GET['action'])) and ($_GET['action'] == 'edit')){
   //Get employees info
        $employees = PDO_FetchAll("select * from employees");

        //echo "<script>alert('AA');</script>";
        //Initial values
        $official_days_e = array();
        $official_vacations_e = array();
        $attendance_days_e = array();
        $present_days_e = array();
        $vacations_e = array();
        $vacations_record_e = array();

        $table_nameE = $_POST['table_name'];

        //echo "<script>alert('BB');</script>";
        foreach($employees as $employee){
            $official_days_e[] = $_POST[$employee['emp_id'].'_official_days_e'];
            $official_vacations_e[] = $_POST[$employee['emp_id'].'_official_vacations_e'];
            $attendance_days_e[] = $_POST[$employee['emp_id'].'_attendance_days_e'];
            $present_days_e[] = $_POST[$employee['emp_id'].'_present_days_e'];
            $vacations_e[] = $_POST[$employee['emp_id'].'_vacations_e'];
            $vacations_record_e[] = $_POST[$employee['emp_id'].'_vacations_record_e'];
        }

        //echo "<script>alert('$official_days_e[1]');</script>";

        //Edit the values in the DB
        $countt = 0;
        foreach($employees as $employee){

            $empl_id = $employee['id'];
            $official_dayss_e = $official_days_e[$countt];
            $official_vacationss_e = $official_vacations_e[$countt];
            $attendance_dayss_e = $attendance_days_e[$countt];
            $present_dayss_e = $present_days_e[$countt];
            $vacationss_e = $vacations_e[$countt];
            $vacations_recordss_e = $vacations_record_e[$countt];

            $countt = $countt+1;

            $attendance->query("update $table_nameE set
            `official_days` = $official_dayss_e,
            `official_vacations` = $official_vacationss_e,
            `attendance_days` = $attendance_dayss_e,
            `present_days` = $present_dayss_e,
            `vacations` = $vacationss_e,
            `vacations_record` = $vacations_recordss_e") or die($attendance->errorInfo());

        }
        //echo "<script>alert('$countt');</script>";
        //echo "<script>alert('Done');</script>";
        echo "<script>playSound('js/sounds/sound1.ogg');</script>";
        echo "<script>$.miniNoty('Done', 'success');</script>";
        //echo "<script>setTimeout(function(){ window.location='attendance.php'; }, 1200);</script>";
}
```

The code works with no errors.
Note that the add form have almost the same code, could it be a ram storing problem ?, I tried to change the variables names but didn't help.

Comment: Are you sure it is not returning errors? I don't see *any* error checking here.

Comment: It might be returning no errors because none of the code is running: if you are form posting it should be `$_POST['action']` not `$_GET['action']`.

Comment: There's no `WHERE` clause on the `UPDATE` statement... if that statement runs, it's going to update every row in the table, every time it runs. There's nothing invalid about that, just very, very strange. That statement also appears to be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks spencer7593, I added where clause and it works. I don't know how I messed it :O